# How to get Flex 3 ComboBox width to adjust based on bound dataProvider contents having changed?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, flex3, combobox, width

In Flex 3, I've created a ComboBox within an MXML component similar to the following:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="comboBox" dataProvider="{_choices}" />

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
  // etc...
  public function get choices():ArrayCollection { return _choices; }

  [Bindable]
  private var _choices:ArrayCollection =
    new ArrayCollection( [ { data: "ALL", label: "All" } ] );
  // etc...
]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:HBox>
```

In the parent MXML application, I'm modifying the contents of the choices property:

```
myComponentId.choices.removeAll();
myComponentId.choices.addItem({data: "NY", label: "New York"});
myComponentId.choices.addItem({data: "CA", label: "California"});
// etc...
```

The binding **is** working in that the ComboBox is automatically picking up the new contents added at runtime, **however** it is not adjusting its width.  The initial width of the ComboBox is wide enough only to show the initial item "All" declared in the component.  However, I want and would have expected the ComboBox to re-size automatically during binding to be able to show "California", but it isn't.

How can I get the ComboBox to update its width after I have added new wider labels to its dataProvider?  Thank you!

Comment: how about setting width to 100% ... as in comboBox.percentWidth = 100;

Comment: http://ifeedme.com/blog/?p=19 -there are nice solutions

Comment: Thanks. That is a nice solution, but to a different problem: Trying to get the dropdown to be a different size than the collapsed control.  I wanted the entire control, collapsed or not, to be the size of the widest item after I changed the contents.  @CapnNefarious's answer of **invalidateSize()** did the trick.

Comment: Everybody: Sorry for not coming back to this sooner.  I've just gone through the solutions and marked the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to call `invalidateProperties()`, `invalidateDisplayList()`, `invalidateSize()`, or some combination of the three (I'm something of a flex newbie myself), to force an update to the component's measurements after changing the data provider or its contents.

```
myComponentId.invalidateSize();
myComponentId.invalidateDisplayList();
myComponentId.invalidateProperties();
```

Comment: +1.  Calling **invalidateSize()** after modifying the choices did update the width.  The other two didn't.

Comment: For what it's worth, this does not seem to work in Flex 4 using the mx:ComboBox control.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a setter for `choices` and call `validateNow()` on the ComboBox at the end of the setter:

```
public function set choices(value:ArrayCollection):void
{
    _choices = value;

    comboBox.validateNow();
}
```

Comment: Calling **validateNow()** on the combobox after modifying the choices did *not* update the width.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and neither of these worked for me. I managed to solve this by creating a new event handler

```
menuComboBox.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, updateListWidth);
```

The method called in this event simply resizes the dropdown.width property.

```
private function updateListWidth(event:ResizeEvent):void {
        menuComboBox.dropdown.width = menuComboBox.width;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't solve the problem.  Actually, assuming I'm reading this code right, it's not quite the problem I was having.  The combo-box, after having its contents modified, didn't have the right size even when *collapsed*.  It wasn't just the dropdown component that was at issue.