# Flex: Make ComboBox dynamically resize so that it will always fit its contents?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I've got a combo box like this:

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{someArrayCollection}" />
```

But when the contents of `someArrayCollection` change, it leaves the combo box too small:

[image]

How can I trick the combo box into automatically resizing to fit the label of the largest item?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Flex 3 ComboBox width to adjust based on bound dataProvider contents having changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428597/how-to-get-flex-3-combobox-width-to-adjust-based-on-bound-dataprovider-contents-h)

Comment: thought i'd ring in... the issue could also be resolved by getting the latest flex sdk.  a bunch of the 3.5 "fixes" broke some of the measure() functionality on the invalidation flag-setting monkey-lovers inside of the dataProvider setter of combobox.  getting an updated version of the sdk might fix any problems you're having.

Comment: For anyone coming across this page from Google with regards to a Spark ComboBox, check out the example over at FlexExamples:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/28/setting-the-width-of-the-dropdown-menu-on-a-spark-dropdownlist-control-in-flex-4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is that the `ComboBox` doesn't `invalidateSize()` after the `dataProvider` dispatches a `COLLECTION_CHANGE` event.

Lame.

It can be fixed by calling `myComboBox.invalidateSize()` when ever the `dataProvider` dispatches a `COLLECTION_CHANGE`.

Comment: +1 for a simple solution.  OF course, if you set a width the invalidateSize() code will have no affect.  In the end, it is always the parents responsibility to size the child, so I can envision situations where this would not work

Comment: “it's always the parent's responsibility to size the child” — hu? That's demonstrably not true. For example, buttons set their own size based on the label size. Parents do have the *option* of setting the size of their children, but it's not their responsibility.

Comment: A child never sizes itself.  It can only make suggestions via the measuredWidth and measuredHeight which the parent can choose to accept or deny.  Read up on the Flex Component Lifecycle or look at the source code of any Flex Component.  The primary use of updateDisplayList is to size and position a component's children.  Find me one component that sets it's own height or width.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you just loop over the dataProvider, measure the width of each item's label, and keep track of the largest one.

I sort of built this into the [Flextras AutoCompletComboBox](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19).  There is a property named [expandDropDownToContent](http://www.flextras.com/AutoCompleteComboBox/docs/asdocs/com/flextras/autoCompleteComboBox/AutoCompleteComboBox.html#expandDropDownToContent) which expands the drop down so it has no scroll bars, but it will not inherently expand the prompt portion.

The Spark DropDownList has a property named typicalItem which does something similar. Oddly that property does not seemed to be defined in the [DropDownList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html#propertySummary) at this time.

---

12/23/3011 update

Since this keeps getting downvoted, I wanted to explicitly state.  When the MX/Halo ComboBox sizes itself automatically, it does so based on only the initial items that will be displayed in the drop down.  If you don't loop over all items in the dataProvider to determine the proper size of the ComboBox/DropDown then items may be cut off regardless of whether you call invalidateSize() or not when items in the dataProvider change.

Comment: It's much simpler than this; see my answer (which is coming soon…)